# How to get [x] and [x+1] into a string then skip to [x+2]

Tags: c#, arraylist

Input : 1 ; a ; 2; b; 3;c;4;d;5;e;6;f

output I'm getting : 1a ; a2;b3;c4;d5;e6

output I want: 1a ; 2b ; 3c; 4d ; 5e; 6f

I know this is a simple thing but I just can't seem to get my damn head around it....

Heres my code:

```
 for (int x = 0; x < coll.Count; x++)
        {
            if (x == 0)
            {
                line.Append(coll[x].ToString());
                line.AppendLine(coll[x + 1].ToString());
            }
            else
            {

                if (x % 2 == 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        line.Append(coll[x].ToString());
                        line.AppendLine(coll[x + 1].ToString());
                        x++;
                        textBox1.Text = line.ToString();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the code the way it is (I'm assuming something will go in the empty conditional), then you just need to change `if (x % 2 == 0)` to `if (x % 2 != 0)` (or equally `if (x % 2 == 1)`), as your code is currently appending to the line when i = 0, then 1, 3,... i.e. all odd numbered indices, whereas you need to be appending to the line at all even numbered indices.

(Unfortunately I can't edit your question, but if you just stick four spaces in front of the line starting with `for` then it should be formatted correctly.)

Comment: turns out I only had to change (x%2 == 0) to (x%2 !=0)...damn thing

Answer (score 0):

If your list is like = [1,a,2,b,3,c,4,d,5,e,6,f]
Try this;

```
String line = "";
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i+2){
  line += list.get(i)+list.get(i+1);      
}
  textBox1.Text = line;
```

**EDIT**
And if you want semi colons;

I edited like

```
    String line = "";
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i+2){
      line += list.get(i)+list.get(i+1);  
      if(i != list.size() - 2){
        line+=";";
      }
    }
      textBox1.Text = line;
```

Comment: Apparently the tags have been edited, `.size()` and `.get(i)` is java I assume? If you replace `.size()` with `.Count` and `.get(i)` with `[i]`, it should be OK. Oh, and the loop iterator variable should have `i += 2` and not just `i+2`.

Comment: It is java or i intented to write java:).I wrote that in here not in an IDE. And thank you for attention:)

Answer (score 0):

One line code with LINQ (but not so efficient):

```
string[] source = { "1", "a", "2", "b", "3", "c" };
var result = source.Zip(source.Skip(1), (s1, s2) => s1 + s2)
                        .Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0);
string[] arrayResult = result.ToArray();
string stringResultWithSeperator = string.Join(";", result);
```

Comment: (Just FYI) You don't need to call `ToArray()`, as `String.Join` works with `IEnumerable<string>`. At least in .NET 4, anyway.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: As you can see, I'm using `result` which is `IEnumerable<string>` in the `Join` method. Adding `ToArray` is telling the OP that we can convert it to an array...

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Another LINQy solution:

```
string input = "1;a;2;b;3;c;4;d;5;e;6;f";

var split = input.Split(';');

string rejoined = String.Join(";", Pairs(split));
```

Where `Pairs` is

```
IEnumerable<string> Pairs(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    if (strings.Take(1).Count() == 0)
    {
        return new string[]{};
    }
    return new [] {String.Join("", strings.Take(2))}.Concat(Pairs(strings.Skip(2)));
}
```